# How to change default model attributes using set method in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have some defults data in Model

```
window.AppState = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: function() {
    return {
      country:  false,
      region: false
    };
  }
});

var appState = new AppState();
```

Then in Router I get array with new values for model like this:

```
[["country", "new country value"], ["region", "new region value"]]
```

And now in a for loop i cycle to update all received params...
I realize it this way

```
appState.attributes[arg] = val;
```

but I think it's not clear, because in documentation of Backbone.js I read about "attribute" method and see this: 
"Please use set to update the attributes instead of modifying them directly."
So my questions is: How i can change attributes of defaults using set method?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try the `.set()` function...

```
appState.set({arg : val});
```

once you set the arguments using `.set()` it will override the default for that.

your example modified a bit:

```
window.AppState = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: function() {
    return {
      country:  false,
      region: false
    };
  }
});

var appState = new AppState();

// when you get your array of new values you can turn it in an object
var myArray = [["country", "new country value"], ["region", "new region value"]];
var newValues = {};
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; ++i)
{
    newValues[myArray[i][0]] = myArray[i][1];
}

// set the properties to the new values
appState.set(newValues);

// if you now return the json of the model, it has changed properties
console.log(appState.toJSON());
```

**remark**
this for loop depends a lot on the structure of your array, the way i wrote it will work for the array you gave in your example, should anything change to that you will need to change the working of the for loop

**remark 2**
if you use this technique more often, you could always extract that functionality in a helper method.

Comment: Yes, that is logic, but my question is, how to make in in cycle:
I mean if i have string with key and string with value, how i can make it using .set()?
For ex. this code not work:
var key = 'country', value = 'some value';
model.set({key, value});

Comment: i changed my answer with what you need to insert the changes. actually they are set as one object, you don't need to loop and set, but you do need a loop to create the object :s

Comment: `var attrs = {}; attrs[key] = value; model.set(attrs);`

Comment: Yes thats true =) Big thanks for you  Sander and  maxl0rd
That is what I mean, now it works perfect.